# I liked the "hold super to view shortcuts" feature of Unity, is there a way to do this using GNOME?

Tags: unity, gnome, 17.10

I have just updated to 17.10 and I'm missing that feature of Unity.

I don't want to revert to Unity because I'm not sure how well that will be supported moving forward.

Comment: Are you talking about launching an application by pressing Super+[some number] ?

Comment: No, just when you held super down a list of all the default shortcut commands would appear.  I didn't realise how much I relied on it when looking up lesser used shortcuts.  Now I have a cheatsheet pdf which isn't quite so nice